# SymmetricDS in Embedded mode in Spring boot app as client

Tags: java, spring-boot, symmetricds

I have a Spring boot app using SymmetricDS. When I want to start a server, and a clients with h2 databases, both in embedded mode.

I created the config files what are read, but the client throws the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'postgresBulkLoaderFactory' defined in class path resource [symmetric-ext-points.xml]:
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [org.jumpmind.symmetric.ext.PostgresBulkDataLoaderFactory]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/jdbc/support/nativejdbc/NativeJdbcExtractor
```

When debugging the config is read for sure. The DB is a H2 database, but by debugging it looks like that SymmetricDS can't find the H2 driver, and It goes back to use Postgresql as default.

My gradle looks like this:

```
 compile group: 'org.jumpmind.symmetric', name: 'symmetric-server', version: '3.5.19'
 compile group: 'org.jumpmind.symmetric', name: 'symmetric-client', version: '3.5.19'
 compile group: 'org.jumpmind.symmetric', name: 'symmetric-core', version: '3.5.19'
```

Why can't it use the my H2 database? Checking maven repository the core should have the h2 driver but the error is still thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using such an old version of SymmetricDS?  The latest is 3.11.8.

When I embed SymmetricDS I exclude dependencies that might interfere with dependencies provided by Spring Boot.  For example:

```
compile ("org.jumpmind.symmetric:symmetric-server:$symmetricVersion") {
     exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
     exclude group: 'com.mangofactory', module: 'swagger-springmvc'
     exclude group: 'org.springframework'
     exclude group: 'net.java.dev.jna'
}
```

This is with the following version of Spring Boot and Spring:

```
springBootVersion=2.1.3.RELEASE
springVersion=5.1.5.RELEASE
```

If you are interested here is an example of how we embed SymmetricDS in Spring Boot:

[SymetricWebServer not starting in embedded mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840245/symetricwebserver-not-starting-in-embedded-mode)

Comment: That is the latest version what can be found as a maven/gradle dependency

Answer (score 1):

The class `org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.NativeJdbcExtractor` is not on the classpath. I'd recommend trying adding to the list of dependencies a jar from Spring that contains this class, for example: https://www.findjar.com/class/org/springframework/jdbc/support/nativejdbc/NativeJdbcExtractor.html

Comment: I have also the following dependency:
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.2.6.RELEASE