# SymetricWebServer not starting in embedded mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, symmetricds

I have a Spring boot maven project with SymetricDS. When I start the application in embedded mode, even if I have a Tomcat with Spring boot, it is looking for Jetty.

```
SymmetricWebServer node = new SymmetricWebServer("server.properties");


<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jumpmind.symmetric</groupId>
   <artifactId>symmetric-server</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/bio/SocketConnector
```

Why is this? Why are the dependencies not downloaded with symetric-server?

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing dependency explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven dependency on Jetty is "provided" because symmetric-server can be built to be a war that can be deployed to any number of web servers.  Here is the essence of how I would embed SymmetricDS in Spring Boot using Spring Boot's provided web container.

```
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.common.ParameterConstants;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.ServerSymmetricEngine;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.SymmetricEngineHolder;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.SymmetricServlet;
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.WebConstants;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class SymDSModule implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    final public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        SymmetricEngineHolder holder = new SymmetricEngineHolder();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put(ParameterConstants.DATA_LOADER_IGNORE_MISSING_TABLES, "true");
        properties.put(ParameterConstants.TRIGGER_CREATE_BEFORE_INITIAL_LOAD, "false");
        properties.put(ParameterConstants.AUTO_RELOAD_ENABLED, "true");
        properties.put(ParameterConstants.AUTO_REGISTER_ENABLED, "true");

        ServerSymmetricEngine serverEngine = new ServerSymmetricEngine(dataSource, applicationContext, properties, false, holder);

        holder.getEngines().put(properties.getProperty(ParameterConstants.EXTERNAL_ID), serverEngine);
        holder.setAutoStart(false);
        servletContext.setAttribute(WebConstants.ATTR_ENGINE_HOLDER, holder);

        serverEngine.setup();
        serverEngine.start();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> symServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new SymmetricServlet(), "/sync");
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this 2 separate classes?

Comment: @GáborCsikós.  No.  Looks like the code was pasted twice.  I fixed the post.

Comment: It just hangs at   ServerSymmetricEngine serverEngine  line

Comment: Can you share the log?

Comment: ServerSymmetricEngine(dataSource, applicationContext, properties, false, holder) 
ServerSymmetricEngine does not have such constuctor

Comment: As for the log:
Error creating bean with name 'domainServerExporter' defined in class path resource [symmetric-jmx.xml]: Error setting property values

Comment: This example was from the latest version of SymmetricDS.   3.11.x.  It is published here:  http://maven.jumpmind.com/repo/

Comment: Wow, thank you i was using mavencentral, and there the highest version was 3.5.9.
Now it works

Comment: It still starts as a client with this configuration:
INFO  [main] o.j.s.AbstractSymmetricEngine - SymmetricDS Node STARTED:
  nodeId=server
  groupId=server
  type=client
  subType=null
  name=server
  softwareVersion=3.11.9
  databaseName=H2
  databaseVersion=1.4
  driverName=H2 JDBC Driver
  driverVersion=1.4.200 (2019-10-14)
  uptime=0 sec.

Comment: I think that is just a side effect of how we created the engine.  The default deployment type is client and we didn't explicitly set it when creating the ServerSymmetricEngine.  You can set it to server explicitly if you want.  Shouldn't make a difference as it is informational.   User setDeploymentType() on the engine to override it.

Comment: Thank you! This is what i did and it started as a server after it.